# How to insert a null value to the database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My query doesn't work. It says there is a **syntax error near null keyword**. I dont know how to fix it. I want to insert an **empty string or null** to the **database**. How can i do it?
This is my query

```
insert into [REMARKS]
values((SELECT top 1 ref_no
FROM A_MASTER order by ref_no desc ), (SELECT top 1 current_dept
FROM A_MASTER order by ref_no desc ),'630590', GETDATE()), NULL
```

Inner queries work without any error.

Comment: Moved last parenthesis ')' [one after getdate()] after null. That is the error.

Comment: Just for reference: NULL is not the same as empty string. NULL is a missing unknown value, which means that you will not be able to apply any arithmetic operations to it. In fact, it is something undetermined.

Comment: Yes that was the mistake. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss placed your close brackets,it should be i like this..

```
 insert into [REMARKS]
 values((SELECT top 1 ref_no
 FROM A_MASTER order by ref_no desc ), (SELECT top 1 current_dept
 FROM A_MASTER order by ref_no desc ),'630590', GETDATE(), NULL)
```

in Your query u referred same table twice for two column.

You can write like..

```
 insert into [REMARKS] select top 1 ref_no,curent_dept 
 '630590',GETDATE(),NULL 
 from A_MASTER 
 order By ref_no desc
```

Since both the columns are from same table..

Comment: Most importantly `Order by` is also same

Answer (score 2):

You have miss placed `close parenthesis` but here is the correct way to insert

```
INSERT INTO [remarks] 
            (ref_no, 
             current_dept, 
             third_col) 
SELECT TOP 1 ref_no, 
             current_dept, 
             NULL 
FROM   a_master 
ORDER  BY ref_no DESC
```

**Note:** Always add insert column list during insertion

Answer (score 0):

I found the mistake. The reason is i have added the **NULL keyword after the close paranthesis** of the insert query. When i added inside the paranthesis it works.

```
insert into [REMARKS]
values((SELECT top 1 ref_no
FROM A_MASTER order by ref_no desc ), (SELECT top 1 current_dept
FROM A_MASTER order by ref_no desc ),'630590', GETDATE(),null)
```

Comment: Better to use my approach which is much simpler, clean, reliable and efficient

Answer (score 0):

Why should we insert NULL in the column if that is nullable and not defined any default value then we simply ignore that column in insertion then it will automatically save null

```
INSERT INTO [remarks] (ref_no, current_dept) 
SELECT TOP 1 ref_no, 
         current_dept 
FROM   a_master 
ORDER  BY ref_no DESC
```

Just mention column definition in the insertion where you want to insert not null value and select the required values for those columns only and don't include the column where you want NULL value.